# how to use Grep to save value from JSON

Tags: json, regex, grep

I just wonder how to save the is_verified: true value "Usernames" only.

```
{
    "users": [{
        "pk": 29394004,
        "username": "chrisbrownofficial",
        "full_name": "Kid INDIGO",
        "is_private": false,
        "is_verified": true,
        "profile_pic_url": "https://instagram.fkwi3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/ef4cc2c1ff4f38a06b852b37fe63f82a/5B8BECFB/t51.2885-19/s150x150/30590388_378690675946907_2025648692966457344_n.jpg",
        "profile_pic_id": "1758771593280949227_29394004",
        "chaining_info": {
            "sources": "[3, 4, 7, 8]"
        },
        "profile_chaining_secondary_label": "Kid INDIGO"
    }, {
        "pk": 17978002,
        "username": "djkhaled",
        "full_name": "DJ KHALED",
        "is_private": false,
        "is_verified": false,
        "profile_pic_url": "https://instagram.fkwi3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/eb6324512b5c034a194acb6bc7bf21de/5B7EBF5A/t51.2885-19/s150x150/28155457_527972687583107_7503145280125009920_n.jpg",
        "profile_pic_id": "1726285422685771850_17978002",
        "chaining_info": {
            "sources": "[2, 3, 4, 7, 8]"
        },
        "profile_chaining_secondary_label": "DJ KHALED"
    }, {
        "pk": 6720655,
        "username": "meekmill",
        "full_name": "Meek Mill",
        "is_private": false,
        "is_verified": true,
        "profile_pic_url": "https://instagram.fkwi3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/0b7220ebde06e977de982518e5e7103b/5B9402A0/t51.2885-19/s150x150/19986196_677620155771292_1453652395958468608_a.jpg",
        "profile_pic_id": "1556078075425574845_6720655",
        "chaining_info": {
            "sources": "[2, 3, 4, 7, 8]"
        },
        "profile_chaining_secondary_label": "Meek Mill"
    }, {
```

Example, saving below because they got          "is_verified": true,
so going to save Username of whoever got "is_verified": true.

```
chrisbrownofficial
meekmill
```

Tried: grep -Po '"is_verified": true'

but with failed attempt.

i hope somebody can help me.

Comment: There are *ix-friendly tools designed just for JSON extraction, like [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/). Using a more focused tool will probably be very time-saving in the end..

Answer (score 0):

If the values for all the properties will be given, how about

```
cat grep2 | grep '"is_verified": true' -B3 | grep '"username":' | sed 's/ *"username": "\(.*\)",/\1/'
```

First `grep` is used to find the entries where `is_verified` value is `true`. The `-B3` option will print 3 lines above the matching line as well. The third line above each `is_verified` is the `username` field.

The second `grep` gets all the `username` fields and from this the username is extracted with sed.

Output is:

```
chrisbrownofficial
meekmill
```

Comment: That doesn't work for some reasons.  [link](https://gyazo.com/73f3e05f1a32f97a4521f7c811b605ec)

Comment: @Terrisamark It seems what you posted in the question is not the input you wanted. In your actual input, the different fields are not in different lines, I guess. Is it all in a single line? Post your actual input.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code might help you:

```
 echo $(cat yourJsonFilePath) | tr "," "\n" | grep '"is_verified": true' -B3 | grep '"username"' | sed -r 's/"username"://' | sed -e 's/"\(.*\)"/\1/'
```

The idea is to replace each "," by "\n". Then, grep the is_verified line and retrieve 3 lines above. Running this code, the result will be:

```
 chrisbrownofficial
 meekmill
```